# Android web service issue

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

```
package com.demowold;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE; 

public class DemoWold extends Activity {

private EditText etUserName;
private TextView lblResult;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Hello";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "Hello";
private static final String URL = "http://ip/foldername/UserAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    lblResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblmsg);
    etUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName); 

       call();

}

public void call()
{
        try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug =true;
        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            lblResult.setText(envelope.getResponse().toString());
        }
        catch(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2)
        {      
            lblResult.setText(androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());         
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());

        }     

            } catch (Exception e) {

        lblResult.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

i am getting error :

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type 
    (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44c25e10)
```

please help me . what is the wrong in code

Comment: Are you solved ? If so, post how, i'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL: `http://ip/foldername/UserAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl` might be the problem. Try `http://ip/foldername/UserAuthenticationService.svc` (supposing ip and foldername will be replaced by the real ones!)

If it doesn't work, could you post what's in `androidHttpTransport.responseDump` after the request?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. For androidHttpTransport.responseDump return empty . i tryed with out wsdl also same result .

Answer (score 0):

The METHOD_NAME and SOAP_ACTION should not be the same. SOAP_ACTION is supposed to be a concatenation of the namespace and method name. In your case it would be "http://tempuri.org/Hello". Also, and this is important, put a slash at the end of NAMESPACE. This is a common problem for ksoap2 beginners, unfortunately.

The error you received doesn't really seem related to them, though.

Where did you put the breakpoint when you inspected responseDump?